# Como chamar uma função javascript que está em um arquivo (.js) separado do cshtml?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Olá, tenho uma página onde os dados de um `DropDownList` são resultado da seleção de um `DropDownList` anterior a este, criei uma função com `javascript` e `ajax` para realizar o filtro, tudo funciona quando o `javascript` está dentro do `cshtml`, porém quando separo a função em um arquivo `.js`, não consigo mais fazer a chamada a `action` dentro da `controller`.
    Abaixo está o pedaço do código onde quero chamar a função que está no arquivo `javascript`:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         @Html.DefaultLabelFor(model => model.CompanhiaId)
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanhiaId, new { Items = Model.CompanhiaList , @onchange = "diretoria(1,'listarByCompany','skill')" } )
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanhiaId)
      </div>
   </div>
```

E aqui a função que fica no arquivo `javascript`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action('listarByCompany','skill')",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function ajaxSucceess(response) {

            var dir = $("#DiretoriaExecutivaId").empty(); //Removendo todos os itens
            dir.append($("<option>Selecione...</option>"));

            $.each(response, function (i, response) {

                dir.append($('<option>', {
                    value: response.Value,
                    text: response.Text
                }));
            });
        }
    });
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Estás a fazer include do ficheiro do javascript?

Comment: Sim Pbras, após fazer o filtro e retornar o json na action, eu acabo por montar o DropDownList com o que foi retornado no filtro.

Comment: Onde está a `function diretoria(){}`

Comment: Está dentro do arquivo diretoria.js na pasta script do projeto web.

Comment: Coloque `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SEU_SCRIPT.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` no seu cshtml criando um .js proprio pra ela, pois se colocar no layout padrao não terá todas as dependencias ainda quando terminar de carregar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal agradeço a atenção e ajuda, consegui solucionar o problema da seguinte forma:

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/diretoria.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Seguindo o comentátio do Victor Laio na primeira linha (obrigado Victor), tirei a chamada do htmlhelper:

Antes:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanhiaId, new { Items = Model.CompanhiaList , @onchange = "diretoria(1,'listarByCompany','skill')" } )`

Depois:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanhiaId, new { Items = Model.CompanhiaList } )`

e acrescentei o código abaixo no cshtml para chamar a função javascript no evento change do DropDownList:

`<script>
        $("#CompanhiaId").change(function () {
           diretoria($("#CompanhiaId").find(":selected").val(), null, "listarByCompany", 
           "skill", "DiretoriaExecutivaId");
        });
 </script>`